# How to access the default MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a link to a audio file. I don't want to create a object using my code for a Mediaplayer and play it, but instead I want to call the inbuilt MediaPlayer app of my android mobile. Is this possible at all. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(audioFileUri, "audio/*"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Or change the last line to `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "play music"));`  to display a app chooser to finish the task.

I have used this piece of code and find that it doesn't work for the audio files for /raw folder. I guess this happens because the player can't get access to the resource from developer's package.